# Disable auto-commit with panda's DataFrame.to_sql

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite, transactions

I pull a couple of tables from an Oracale database with pandas' `DataFrame.read_sql_query` and insert it into a local sqlite database with `DataFrame.to_sql`. Then I validate it and throw an exception that should rollback the changes if a validation failes.

Unfortunatelly calling `DataFrame.to_sql` commits the sqlite transation so that a failed validation can't rollback the changes.

I handle the transaction with this context manager:

```py
@contextmanager
def transaction(connection: sqlite3.Connection) -> sqlite3.Connection:
    connection.isolation_level = None
    connection.execute("begin;")
    try:
        yield connection
        connection.execute("commit;")
    except Exception:
        connection.execute("rollback;")
        raise
```

It first fails on the commit line with `OperationalError` telling me there is no open transation to fail with exactly the same error on rollback, which is understandable.

---

Is there a way to instruct pandas to not commit its operation or do I have to rewrite it with *manual* inserts or use a different sqlite library?

Answer (score 0):

Since I had no luck with the standard `sqlite3` library I tried it with `sqlalchemy` and the following approach does the trick:

```py
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"sqlite:///c:\\path\\to\\db.sqlite")
    with sqlalchemy.orm.Session(bind=engine) as session, session.begin():
        ...
        data: pd.DataFrame = ...
        data.to_sql("table_name", session.connection(), if_exists="append", index=False)
        ...
```